# How do I limit simultaneous connections to a port with UFW?

Tags: linux, port, ufw

I see many articles regarding brute attacks, number of connections per N seconds, but in my case is different, i have a proxy server and i just want to limit connections from anywhere to 1 at the time... again, not from the same IP, but from anywhere... i tried using ufw limit but that is for connections coming from the same IP Address, i just want that, if somebody is currently connected to port 3128 then nobody else can connect until the current connection is finished.

Comment: In general I'd think that this is a very bad idea to limit the proxy in this way.

You could try to limit this in the software itself, but I'd rather say: please don't do such things.

Answer (score 1):

UFW is using *iptables* as backend. UFW's *limit* rule is based on iptables' [*recent*](https://manpages.debian.org/iptables/iptables-extensions.8#recent) match which is not intended for OP's use case. The relevant feature would instead be the [*connlimit*](https://manpages.debian.org/iptables/iptables-extensions.8#connlimit) match (and for *nftables* the [*ct count*](https://manpages.debian.org/bullseye/nftables/nft.8#CONNTRACK_EXPRESSIONS) expression).

> `connlimit`
>
> Allows you to restrict the number of parallel connections to a server
> per client IP address (or **client address block**).

Alas, this feature is not made available directly by UFW which is called the *Uncomplicated* Firewall for a reason. Instead, to provide missing functionalities, [UFW offers](https://serverfault.com/questions/198398/ubuntu-how-to-add-an-iptables-rule-that-ufw-cant-create) [to load any custom iptables rules](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UncomplicatedFirewall#Advanced_Functionality) from files (as long as it's not in `user.rules`/`user6.rules`). So this answer will actually be an *iptables* answer hidden inside an UFW answer.

The standalone *iptables* rule to limit the concurrent number of connections on tcp port 3128 to one could be written like this:

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 3128 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -m connlimit --connlimit-upto 1 --connlimit-mask 0 --connlimit-saddr -j ACCEPT
```

`-m conntrack --ctstate NEW` verifies only new connections, `--connlimit-mask 0 --connlimit-saddr` will match any source address, and `--connlimit-upto 1` will allow only one *conntrack* entry matching the conditions for the result to be true.

This rule should be put, in `iptables-save` format (just meaning there's no leading `iptables` command), in the dedicated custom chain called `ufw-after-input` defined in the `/etc/ufw/after.rules`. So it will use `-A ufw-after-input` instead of `-A INPUT`.

The end of `/etc/ufw/after.rules` should now read like this (at least for UFW 0.36):

```perl
# don't log noisy broadcast
-A ufw-after-input -m addrtype --dst-type BROADCAST -j ufw-skip-to-policy-input

# allow only one established connection to port 3128
-A ufw-after-input -p tcp --dport 3128 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -m connlimit --connlimit-upto 1 --connlimit-mask 0 --connlimit-saddr -j ACCEPT

# don't delete the 'COMMIT' line or these rules won't be processed
COMMIT
```

and the firewall rules reloaded:

```
ufw reload
```

---

Notes:

- Local connections won't be affected, and the rule can't be made to work correctly with local connections for multiple reasons. Verifying this rule must be done from remote.
- IPv6: One can insert the same entry (starting this time with `-A ufw6-after-input`) in the same way in `/etc/ufw/after6.rules`. Note that *iptables* and *ip6tables* won't coalesce the two counts together: this will then allow one IPv4 connection plus one IPv6 connection.
- While examples often use `--syn`, using `-m conntrack --ctstate NEW` allows to replace the TCP protocol with UDP just by using `-p udp` instead of `-p tcp`, should the need arise.
- Abnormal disconnections from the single allowed client (eg: loss of connectivity) might result in the socket being in FIN_WAIT states and would incur delays before being usable again. Also a browser using a proxy is likely to attempt multiple simultaneous connections through it. Allowing only one connection might disrupt the browser's behaviour with the default *deny*/*DROP* rule. Allowing more than one simultaneous connection, using an inverted *iptables* rule ending with `-j REJECT` or a `ufw default reject incoming` policy should be considered.